# Centralizing the dots in equations

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

Folks, forgive me for answering this question. I'm unable to centralize dots in equations though i believe that the script is right. Could you please advise on the following:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
    r_1.......\\
    r_2.......\\
    \vdots\\
    r_n........
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: It would have been better if you provided a complete [**MWE**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/1424). It is also not so clear what your problem is: Are you talking about the dots `....`? If so, the answer is to replace them with `\cdots`. Or do you mean the horizontal placement of `\vdots`? If so, using `cases` is the wrong approach. As I see no ampersands (`&`) here, I wonder if `cases` is *really* what you want. A proper MWE might help to clear this up.

Answer (score 2):

You can have this simple code with `mathtools` (which is an extension of `amsmath`, so needless to load the latter package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{dcases}
    \begin{aligned}
    r_1 & =\cdots \\
    r_2 & = \cdots \\[-1.5ex]
    &\vdotswithin{ = } \\[-1ex]
    r_n & = \cdots
    \end{aligned}
\end{dcases} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`*Explanation*:

the `dcacses` environment is a  variant of the standard `cases` defined by `mathtools` in which everything is in `\displaystyle`. `\vdotswithin{symbol}` produces a `\vdot` centred w.r.t. the alignment symbol.

Comment: `aligned` uses `\displaystyle` by itself.

Comment: @egreg: yes, but I wanted to explain what's `dcases` w.r..t. `cases`. One does not always use cases with aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `array` to achieve correct alignment. And use `\left\{ ... \right.` instead of `cases`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lcl}
    r_1 & = &.....\\
    r_2 & = &.....\\
    &\vdots&\\
    r_n & = & .....
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: using `array` gives weird spacing around the `=` and sets the items in textsyle not displaystyle, it would be far better to use an `amsmath` alignment environment.